# Lots of DESCRIBE queries in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, query-optimization

I just set up FirePHP in Zend and I'm noticing a huge number of DESCRIBE queries. Some pages have 50 or more identical queries all on the same table. e.g.

```
0.00198     connect      NULL
0.00449 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00041 SELECT `nodes`.* FROM `nodes` WHERE (((`nodes`.`id` = 111)))    NULL
0.0037  DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00155 SELECT `nodes`.* FROM `nodes` WHERE (((`nodes`.`id` = 111)))    NULL
0.00059 SELECT `nodes`.* FROM `nodes` WHERE (parent_id = '111') ORDER BY `order` ASC, `id` ASC  NULL
0.00366 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.0054  DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.0049  DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00519 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00492 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00691 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00741 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.0048  DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00556 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00516 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
0.00487 DESCRIBE `nodes`    NULL
```

...and it goes on.

Are all those DESCRIBE queries generated by the framework (I'm using Zend_DbTable)? Are they all necessary? Should I be worried about them or are they not likely to be impacting performance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those queries are executed by Zend_Db_Table to detect the schema of the tables. You can ask Zend_Db_Table to cache the results using a Zend_Cache to prevent constant calls, but bare that in mind if you change the schema.

You can do so by using:

```
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
```

Comment: I am interested in this. Do you know of a good in-depth resource on setting up the $cache portion?

Comment: Check out the Zend Framework manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.metadata.caching

Comment: I've read that.  I am looking for something with suggestions on the pros/cons of different settings, like what cache type to use, what directory to use when using the 'file' type, etc.

Comment: You either ask the cache to delete the keys used by Zend_Db_table (would have to look them up), or you act according to the specific backend being used (delete the cache file, restart the memcached server)... you could probably write a cache wrapper that persists keys, and have a script read it and remove those keys (so they will remain updated all the time)

Answer (score 3):

`Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::describeTable()` does these queries to get the Metadata of your tables when using `Zend_Db_Table` This is used for instance when you do not specify a primary key explicitly. You can enable the MetaData cache or just use `Zend_Db` instead of `Zend_Db_Table`.

I *think* you should not have this many describe queries though. Once a `Zend_Db_Table` instance is set up, it will store the metadata after the first query for the remaining request. Try to use Zend_Debugger or Xdebug to find out what's causing this.

See

- [ZF API entry for `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstact::describeTable()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Adapter/Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract.html#describeTable)
- [ZF manual entry for List and Describe Tables in Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.list-describe)
- [ZF manual entry for Zend_Db_Table with additional background info on metadata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html)

Comment: This is done EVERY TIME new instance of Zend_Db_Table is created. That's why it happened so many times.

Comment: @tomas yes, and that's why it puzzles me because there should be no reason to create the instance multiple times in one request.

Comment: I was instantiating a dbTable for every instance of the model. I've solved it by caching the dbTable instance as a static property on the model.

Comment: @Tamlyn Zend_Db_Table is a Table Data Gateway. This means one instance controls all data in the table, so there should be no need to instantiate multiple tables of the same class.

Answer (score 3):

I used a singleton pattern to store the Zend_DbTable instances in a static array on my base model class. This reduces the DB queries to one per request which is good enough for me and also reduces the number of objects which need to be instantiated.

For example:

```
protected $_dbTable;
protected $_table; //override the database table name in subclass

private static $_dbTableCache = array();

public function __construct()
{
    $this->_dbTable = $this->getDbTableInstance($this->_table);
}

protected function getDbTableInstance($tableName) {
    if (self::$_dbTableCache[$tableName] === null) {
        self::$_dbTableCache[$tableName] = new Zend_Db_Table($tableName);
    }
    return self::$_dbTableCache[$tableName];
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar, using the Zend_Registry.

Comment: Why do you have multiple instances at all? I mean, for multiple tables yes, but you don't need multiple instances of the same table, do you?